# How to log in user after OpenId authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, dotnetopenauth

You will have to forgive me for not knowing the magic behind OpenId. In my flow; the user is directed from an external site and authenticated with OpenId. They are returned to my app to create an additional username and password. They register their account with my app and are logged in.

When they launch my app from their site after they are registered (the external site), I need to have to user logged in automatically, honouring the OpenId credentials.

I'm using the following code:

```
    internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null) { }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XSRF_KEY] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
```

Then redirected to this function after that:

```
        var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (response == null)
        {
            Identifier id;
            if (Identifier.TryParse(_identifer, out id))
            {
                try
                {
                    return openid.CreateRequest(_identifer).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResultMvc5();
                } catch (ProtocolException e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Message);
                }
            }
            return View("Login");
        }
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                Session["FriendlyIdentifier"] = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
                // Now I need to log in the user
                break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
               break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
               break;
        }
```

After a response is returned and authenticated from the OpenIdRelyingParty, I need to log in the user. Do I need to enable form authentication in order for this to work? I'm using MVC Identity 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of what I have in my `public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)` method, which is the method called from the external OpenId server (Intuit's in this case, but it shouldn't matter).

```
//Attempt to log the user in if they've already created an account with the external login.
if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
{        
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```